# Do they make a 120 volt programmable thermostat?

Tags: thermostat

I have an oil burner with hot water baseboard heat. My thermostat is 120 volts. Do they make a programmable thermostat for my system?

Answer (score 1):

If they don't, a 24V thermostat, a 24V programmable relay, a 24V transformer, and a box add up to the same thing. Which is how your 24V thermostat controls your 120V household heating system, after all.

Answer (score -1):

"Your system" is a bit of an unknown. But there are certainly 120V/240V programmable thermostats. The catch is that they tend to be more expensive than the typical low-voltage thermostats. An example [arbitrarily selected from a search on Home Depot](https://www.homedepot.com/p/King-Electric-Hoot-WiFi-Line-Voltage-7-Day-Programmable-Thermostat-120-208-240V-Double-Pole-K902-W/318591992):

[image: Line Voltage Thermostat]

This particular one is currently > $300, when similar sorts of low-voltage thermostats (i.e., fancy display, WiFi, etc.) are available starting at under $100. The fundamental differences should be just a bigger relay or contactor for switching the HVAC system and a power-supply to convert mains AC to low-voltage to power the electronics (but consider a UL/ETL-listed USB adapter is available to convert 120V/240V AC to 5V DC for under $10) which shouldn't add much to the cost.

I suspect the main reason for much higher cost is volume production. In the US (can't speak for other countries), 49% of heating is via Natural Gas (most of which is forced air, probably a very small percentage boilers/hot water radiators/etc.) and 34% electric (which includes heat pumps as well as resistance heat, and even much of the resistance heat is set up as a "furnace" with low-voltage thermostat controls rather than 120V/240V line-voltage baseboard heat). And many boilers or other systems have been adapted for low-voltage thermostat control in order to combine control of heating and air conditioning. So the market for low-voltage thermostats is simply much larger than that of line-voltage thermostats. More competition. Lower prices.